# Import csv data (SDK iphone)

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, csv, nsstring

For the following code, I can read all the data in the string, and successfully get the data for plot.

```
NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *filePath = @"995,995,995,995,995,995,995,995,1000,997,995,994,992,993,992,989,988,987,990,993,989";
NSArray *myText = [filePath componentsSeparatedByString:@","];  
NSInteger idx;    
for (idx = 0; idx < myText.count; idx++) {
    NSString *data =[myText objectAtIndex:idx];
    NSLog(@"%@", data);
    id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0+idx*0.002777778];
    id y = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:data];          
    [contentArray addObject:
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y", nil]];    
}

self.dataForPlot = contentArray;
```

then, I try to load the data from a CSV file, the data in Data.csv file has the same value and the same format as:

```
995,995,995,995,995,995,995,995,1000,997,995,994,992,993,992,989,988,987,990,993,989.
```

I run the code, it is supposed to give the same graph output. however, it seems that the data is not loaded from the CSV file successfully.
I cannot figure out what's wrong with my code.

```
NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *Data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil ];    
if (Data)
{
    NSArray *myText = [Data componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSInteger idx;    
    for (idx = 0; idx < myText.count; idx++) {
        NSString *data =[myText objectAtIndex:idx];
                    NSLog(@"%@", data);
        id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0+idx*0.002777778];
        id y = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:data];        
        [contentArray addObject:
        [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y",nil]];    
    }
    self.dataForPlot = contentArray;

}
```

The only difference is

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *Data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil ];   
if (data){
}
```

Did I do anything wrong here?

Comment: Please log the return values of `pathForResource:ofType:` and `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` and edit your question to include the output. Please also stop suppressing that error return—change `error:nil` to `error:&nameOfAVariableYouCreateToHoldAnNSErrorObject` and log that object, and edit your question to include *that* output. The frameworks often try to tell you what you're doing wrong; when you pass `NULL` (or `nil`) to an error return, you prevent them from doing that.

Comment: As a point of style, may I suggest that "data" is not the most meaningful variable name, and having two distinct variables named "data" and "Data" is downright confusing.

+1 for "don't ignore the error return, it might be trying to tell you something"

Comment: Calling a string variable “data” is confusing on its own, since there is an NSData class, and I, for one, am more likely to name a variable “data” if it holds an NSData object.

Answer (score 9):

I setup a sample project and tried this code and it worked.

The two most probable points of error are

1. you aren't getting the file path (i.e. filePath is nil)
2. you aren't reading the file correctly.

I would suggest adding:

```
NSLog( @"filePath: %@", filePath );

NSLog( @"Data: %@", Data );
```

and changing:

```
NSString *Data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil ];
```

to

```
NSError*  error;
NSString* Data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error ];
```

and then adding:

```
NSLog( @"error: %@", error );
```

Of course, running this through the debugger and checking the return values should work as well and let you know exactly where it is failing.

Comment: thanks for your help!!!
yeah, i tracked the location of the data file and make sure i am getting the right path. it works!!