# Convert CSV File for use in phone program?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a big excel file and I want to be able to use this in my app and sort by name. I have 3 columns, name, height and weight.

Any advice would be so very greatly appreciated...I've been trying to do this for days and I don't know how to!

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936281/iphone-app-that-reads-csv-file

Comment: No, i want to know how I can get my app to read the data and sort the data on a CSV file. not if I can open it on an iPhone! Thanks anyway. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Your app will be running on an iPhone, so you should be reading and writing your CSV on the iPhone. You must parse a CSV before you can sort it. Could you explain what you are looking for?

Comment: I am intending to do a sort for people and see what their height and weight are. I have a huge CSV file with the details on that I want to be able to let my app read and display, only within the app, not just have a CSV reader. I can do all the nice layout and everything, I just don't know how to call the data from the CSV file.

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting, a CSV reader ;) But CSV isn't a very nice format, IMO, so I'd suggest you convert it to XML (as XML is much more versatile and easy to parse).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about parsing an actual CSV file in your iPhone app, but just about accessing the data, I would think about converting the CSV data into a .plist format. plist files (in text format) are very handy because they're human readable and you can suck the contents into an `NSDictionary` or similar data structure at runtime with very little effort.

This is addressed in this question:

[Convert Excel document (xls) to a plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546007/convert-excel-document-xls-to-a-plist)

I've personally used the 'make a formula inside your spreadsheet to generate .plist file contents' approach successfully several times before. See [Christopher Fairbairn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546007/convert-excel-document-xls-to-a-plist/1611187#1611187) at the above link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

A 3 column csv is a doddle to parse, assuming you've got control over it and there are no silly quoted commas or anything.

You can do it with the following untested pseudo-sorta-typed-on-my-phone-code:

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"myFile.csv" encoding:_whatever_ error:nil];
NSMutableArray *parsedData = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *lines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

for (NSString *line in lines)
{
    NSArray *fields = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    // add a dictionary or whatever to your array containing the relevant values from fields...
}
```