# iOS MapKit Showing Many Places From File

Tags: ios, mapkit

Im relatively new to iOS development and have been asked to make an app whereby I can place a load of pins on a map. I have been given an csv file with the lat, long, an identifier and some info for each of the places I need to plot but I'm not sure as to the best way to go from here. Any help is very appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

My Advise is to divide your task:

1 - Create a class to hold your coordinates and other useful information (name of the place, phone number, etc)

2- Create a parser, so you can parse your CSV file.

3- Add your data to your map.

Use the following links to help you out:

- [Import csv data (SDK iphone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444975/import-csv-data-sdk-iphone)
- http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/03/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit-part-2/

Since you are new to this, take your time understanding what's going on. There are no shortcuts when learning. If you need more help, use my email so I can assist you.